# Xcode Project Name Change

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, bundle-identifier, xcode-project

I know there a lot of questions on this that I've been trying to look through. I changed my app's name successfully but the bundle ID as well as the Target names still reflect the previous project's name. Is this fine for when I submit it to the app store?

Comment: when u test the app what the name it shows?

Comment: yes its fine. what you need is only bundle name that will reflect under the app icon.

Comment: @BuntyMadan thanks. The name that appears under the app icon is the correct name. I just wanted to make sure. First time submitting to the store and I wasn't sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bundle ID` will not be seen by any one else than the development team,

but It will be wise to change it before you first submit your app.

if you are submitting your app for the second time and if you change the `Bundle ID` then it will be treated as a new app. So after submission you can change your `App Name`, but not your `Bundle ID`

Hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: I would say that the bundle ID is not *easily* seen by anyone else, but it can be seen in the .ipa, in addition to `~/Library` directories.

Comment: True, but only to people with development skills, or very advanced users, but for normal people it should be fine